# Is it possible to convert an inout signal to two signals (in and out) in VHDL?

Tags: input, port, converters, vhdl, output

When I have an entity like this:

```
entity outer_inout is
  Port(
    clk       : in  std_logic;
    rst       : in  std_logic;
    s         : in  std_logic;
    d         : inout std_logic;
    ...       -- some ports
  );
end entity;
```

Is it possible to change the whole design so that no inout port is used?

```
entity outer_inout2 is
  Port(
    clk       : in  std_logic;
    rst       : in  std_logic;
    s         : in  std_logic;
    d_in      : in  std_logic;
    d_out     : out std_logic;
    ... -- some ports
  );
end entity;
```

I guess in some special cases it is possible to convert the inout port to an in and an out port. But the question is: Is this always possible? Can the inout port always be replaced in a design so that the two designs is semantically equivalent?

Comment: What does the `if d='1'` code do? When `s` is 1, it's just an oscillator. Have you posted the right code? Your current inout code needs a direction control and some way to disable driving of `d`.

Comment: Is that the whole of the code writing to the `d` signal?  If so, you have no opportunity to send anything different 'in' from outside as you never drive with a 'Z' or other "weak" signal to be overridden.  Can you say more about your code and why you want ot remove the inout?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your 's' signal is. But this is what you want, assuming `d` is a tristatable output with `s` = 1 to enable

```
d_in <= d;
d <= d_out when s = '1' else 'Z';
```

If you have an open-collector output - you'll have a pullup in your testbench somewhere driving the `d` signal with an 'H', and then you can do:

```
d_in <= to_X01(d);
d <= '0' when d_out = '0' else 'Z';
```

Comment: He wants to convert from `inout`, not to `inout`.